# Regular expression to resemble the input attribute

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jumbly html form which are different order of attributes,
such as:

```
<li><input type="text" name="tel" value="" id="tel" class="form1"></li>
<li><input type="text" value="" id="tel" class="form1"    name="tel" ></li>
<li><input type="text" name="tel" id="tel"  value=""  class="form1"></li>
<li>
    <select name="tel" id="tel" class="form1">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</li>
<li><input name="tel" id="tel" type="text" value=""  class="form1"></li>
```

SO I'm hope it be regular,the first attribute is type,
and then are name, id, value, class etc.,
like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Common" id="" value="" class="">
```

Now I'm trying to come up with a solution:to catch the name attribute etc.

**Pattern delimited by**

```
(<input)(.*)(\bname\s*=['"](.*?)['"])
```

**Replacement**

```
$1 $3$2
```

But it's result was just match name attributes,
how can it capture other attributes and sort this well organized?

```
<li><input name="tel" type="text"  value="" id="tel" class="form1"></li>
<li><input name="tel" type="text" value="" id="tel" class="form1"     ></li>
<li><input name="tel" type="text"  id="tel"  value=""  class="form1"></li>
<li>
    <select name="tel" id="tel" class="form1">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</li>
<li><input name="tel"  id="tel" type="text" value=""  class="form1"></li>
```

Comment: You should use a parser, not regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. At least not HTML which is *not* regular. There are HTML parsers for this, e.g. JSoup.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use a parser, but it really can exchange attributes by parser?

Comment: @kkasp: ahem... please... "first attribute" instead of "fist attribute". Peace and love ;)

Comment: @max66 thanks, I edited it.